# How to create tab into a link

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="captionBottom">
    <a href="mp.aspx" title=""><img src="c.jpg" alt="" /></a>
    <figcaption>View!</figcaption>
</div>
```

The `figcaption` is shown over the image when hovered.

How can I make that a link to the `href` of the anchor tag, so clicking on the `figcaption` also takes the user to `mp.aspx`

CSS:

```
figcaption {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background: #e55302;
    background: rgba(229,83,2,0.90);
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 10px 0;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.6s ease;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.captionBottom:hover figcaption {
  opacity: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: If You want to create a Anchor Link Tool tip You can review this link http://designshack.net/articles/css/html5-css3-anchor-link-tooltips/ Or Try a demo http://designshack.net/tutorialexamples/anchor-tooltips/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using jQuery:

```
$('figcaption').on('click',function()
{
    var figHref = $(this).prev().attr('href');
    window.location.href = figHref; //changed the code.
});
```

Comment: I have to use `$(this).closest()` because it is generated using XSLT and there can be random links.

Comment: I tried this: `$("figcaption").on("click", function () {
     var j = $(this).closest('a').attr("href");
     alert(j);
    });` but it alerted `undefined`

Comment: Well I beat you to it ;)! hehe. But it is saying `undefined`

Comment: I wasn't sure if i posted a comment or edited my post :) Give me a sec ;)

Comment: If you use the same order like 'a' then 'figcaption', you can use .prev() that gives back reference to the previous element

Comment: No problem. Wish you luck and fun! :) And thank you ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
<a href="mp.aspx" title="">
 <img src="c.jpg" alt="" />
 <figcaption>View!</figcaption>
</a>
```